# Cannot view GitLab "tags" page from an imported Github repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I imported a Github repository following the instructions [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/Import-existing-repositories-into-GitLab).

Everything worked as expected, however, when I attempt to view the "tags" page (e.g. git.example.com/some-namespace/my-repo-name/tags) I get the "Error 500 - We're sorry, but something went wrong" page.

When I visit the "Commits" page (e.g. git.example.com/some-namespace/my-repo-name/commits/master) the "Tags" tab shows the right number of tags. I can even successfully filter by the tags under on "Network" page.

When I create a new project the normal way through the GitLab interface, I can view the "Tags" page no problem; it's only with imported repositories.

Any insight would be appreciated!

---

- Gitlab v6.1.0
- Running on Linux/Debian OS
- Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a issue in progress (that you can reopen) on this exact bug:

[Issue 4923: 500 error when viewing */tags page](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4923): seen with GitLab 6.0+.

Comment: Thanks VonC for finding that! I'll add a new issue as indicated.